# Are all reference types class types in C#?

Tags: c#, class, types, reference

Is there any reference type in C# which is not a class? does the constraint in following generic, include all reference types?

```
static void f<T>() where T : class
{
    T t = default;
    Console.WriteLine(t);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are asking 2 different questions:

> Are all reference types class types in C#?

No.

> does the constraint in following generic [`where T : class`], includes all reference types?

Yes, it will constrain all *reference types*.

---

**Firstly**, let's determine what a *reference type* actually is.

[Reference types (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types)

> There are two kinds of types in C#: *reference types* and *value types*.
> Variables of reference types store references to their data (objects),
> while variables of value types directly contain their data.
>
> The following keywords are used to declare reference types:
>
> - class
> - interface
> - delegate
>
> C# also provides the following built-in reference types:
>
> - dynamic
> - object
> - string

<sub>***Note** : Not mentioned above, `Array` types are also reference types derived from the `abstract` base type `Array`*</sub>

**Secondly**, let's work out what the *class constraint* constrains

[Constraints on type parameters (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters)

> `where T : class`
>
> The type argument must be a reference type. This constraint applies
> also to any *class*, *interface*, *delegate*, or *array type*.

<sub>***Note** : Not mentioned above, the `class` constraint also includes `dynamic`*</sub>

---

As a Bonus fact, since *C# 7.3* you can also explicitly constrain by *delegate*

**Delegate constraints**

> Also beginning with *C# 7.3*, you can use `System.Delegate` or
> `System.MulticastDelegate` as a base class constraint. The CLR always
> allowed this constraint, but the C# language disallowed it